# Função SE com 3 valores finais

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções, vba, excel-vba, fórmula

---*Reformulando a pergunta*---

Uma fórmula que expresse as seguintes informações:

-Quando a Coluna I e J estiver escrito "Letra N" vai retornar na coluna C a escrita "PSI"

-Quando a Coluna K e L estiver escrito "Letra N" vai retornar na coluna C a escrita "SI"

-Quando a Coluna I , J , K e L estiver escrito "Letra N" em todas essas 4 colunas vai retornar na coluna C a escrita "C/D"

**OBS:** Meu excel não tem a opção da função **SES**.

Comment: mas qual a dúvida? ou é pra resolvermos o problema?

Comment: Se possivel me explicar como a função SES pode ser substituida pois não consegui encontrar nenhuma função que faça isso a não ser a função SES, porém onde irei aplicar não temos disponível esse recurso

Comment: Você tem que discriminar mais precisamente as combinações. Por exemplo "Quando não for "A" nem "B" retonar "C/D"" você está se referindo a que colunas? "A' na coluna L e "B" na coluna J ou em uma única coluna? Ambas as condições tem que ocorrer ou basta uma condição? Defina precisamente o que deseja, sem deixar margens a possíveis interpretações, que ficará mais fácil ajuda-lo.

Comment: a função SES pode ser substituída pelas funções `SE` e `OU`, por exemplo: `SE(OU(J1="A";L1="B");"IGUAL";"DIFERENTE")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocar na célula C1, e copiar para as demais células da coluna:

```
=SE(E(I1="N"; J1="N"; K1="N"; L1="N"); "C/D"; SE(E(I1="N"; J1="N"); "PSI"; SE(E(K1="N"; L1="N"); "SI"; "Não é nenhuma das alternativas")))
```